# Bootstrap 3 - General structure template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the next template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: gray; height: 100%;"></div>
<div class="col-md-9" style="background-color: blue; height: 100%; padding: 0; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div id="layer1" class="col-md-5" style="background-color: red; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div id="layer2" class="col-md-7" style="background-color: brown; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

All right.

But if i add a image in layer with id="layer1":

```
<div class="col-md-9" style="background-color: blue; height: 100%; padding: 0; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div id="layer1" class="col-md-5" style="background-color: red; height: 100%;">
        <img src="Sin título.png" height="1000" />
    </div>
    <div id="layer2" class="col-md-7" style="background-color: brown; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

The height of layers with id="layer1" and  id="layer2", must be equal that the image height.

I see it like this:

[image]

and should be see it like this:

[image]

This is the css code:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}
```

If i hide the image, and add other html elements, the problem is the same:

```
<div class="col-md-5" style="background-color: red; height: 100%;">
    <!--<img src="Sin título.png" height="100%" />-->
    <p>Litera1</p>
    <p>Litera2</p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>aaaa</td></tr>
        <tr><td>bbbb</td></tr>
        <tr><td>cccc</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dddd</td></tr>
        <tr><td>eeee</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ffff</td></tr>
        <tr><td>gggg</td></tr>
        <tr><td>hhhh</td></tr>
    </table>
    <p>Litera3</p>
    <p>Litera4</p>
    <h1>Litera5</h1>
    <p>Litera6</p>
    <p>Litera7</p>
    <p>Litera8</p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>aaaa</td></tr>
        <tr><td>bbbb</td></tr>
        <tr><td>cccc</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dddd</td></tr>
        <tr><td>eeee</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ffff</td></tr>
        <tr><td>gggg</td></tr>
        <tr><td>hhhh</td></tr>
    </table>
    <h1>Litera9</h1>
    <p>Litera10</p>
    <p>Litera11</p>
    <p>Litera12</p>
    <p>Litera13</p>
    <p>Litera14</p>
    <p>Litera15</p>
    <p>Litera16</p>
    <p>Litera17</p>
    <p>Litera18</p>
</div>
```

How could do it?, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have made the height of the image 1000px with the following line

```
<img src="Sin título.png" height="1000" />
```

Change it to 100% and your problem should be solved

```
<img src="Sin título.png" height="100%" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not solve the problem, i have actualized the question.

Comment: is easy, i only have that to delete the style height, sorry thanks